# always getting error trying to elaborate sql query into cakephp; how to convert this one?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

If I use the Following code in PHPMyAdmin (SQL) statement, it works and I get a list of all Birthdays of the following  31 days. Here is my code:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    membres 
WHERE
    DATE_ADD(
        date_de_naissance,
        INTERVAL
            YEAR(CURDATE()) -
            YEAR(date_de_naissance) +
            IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(date_de_naissance), 1, 0)
        YEAR
    )
    BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
    AND
    (
        MONTH(date_de_naissance) <> MONTH(CURDATE())
        OR
        DAY(date_de_naissance) <> DAY(CURDATE())
    )
```

How would it be in Cakephp? Please help

Answer (score 1):

I generally find it's much easier to do the date math in CakePHP than in MySQLs, so I'd do something like this:

```
$birthday_members = $this->Membres->find()
    ->where([
        'date_de_naissance >' => Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::now(),
        'date_de_naissance <=' => Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::now()->addDays(31),
    ]);
```

Comment: As I have 3.4x, Here is the message: Error: [Error] Class 'App\Controller\FrozenDate' not found in

Comment: I was assuming that you know how namespaces work in PHP; it really makes the code more readable to not add that clutter. Either add a `use` for that class at the top of the file, or put the full class namespace in the code here.

Comment: FrozenDate  is not a class available in 3.4x how to have it available? or modify proposed statement ..

Comment: It is, in fact, [available in 3.4](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.I18n.FrozenDate.html).